# How to prevent Game Center pop-ups to mess up with my landscape-only views' orientations?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, game-center, gamekit

My iPad application is landscape only and supports the Game Center framework.

After the following sequence:

1. the authentication Game Center popup is shown,
2. the user decides to create a profile
3. the detailed account-creation popup managed by the GameKit framework is displayed
4. the user cancels the operation

my app has messed up views: the views have rotated 90° degrees on the left.

[image: Description of the messy views]

At this point, rotating the app won't help, and I need to relaunch my app to get the thing fixed.

Of course, all my low-level view controllers involved (except the root navigation controller which is a basic UINavigationController) are implementing the following method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Any idea why I get such a messy behavior?